# Mergesort using Vectors not sorting correctly

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, mergesort

I'm working on Mergesort to refresh my memory of it. I'm doing it from a text file of people I created. For some reason I can't seem to debug... the sort isn't really sorting anything at all. I have the correct functions and loops but there must be something small going on that I'm not noticing. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Person {
    string DOB;
    string balance;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string state;

    Person() { }

    Person(string DOB, string firstName, string lastName, string state, string balance) {
        this->DOB = DOB;
        this->firstName = firstName;
        this->lastName = lastName;
        this->state = state;
        this->balance = balance;
    }

    void print() {
        cout << DOB << " "
        << balance << " "
        << firstName<< " "
        << lastName << " "
        << state  << " "
        << balance  << "\n";
    }
};

void print(vector<Person*> arr, int size) { // print function for array debuggin'
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        cout << arr[i]->lastName << " | ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void merge(vector<Person*> arr, int start, int mid, int end) {
    int leftSize = mid - start + 1;
    int rightSize = end - mid;
    int leftIndex, rightIndex;
    int masterIndex = start;

    vector<Person*> tmpR; // arrays to represent our two sections of the total array
    vector<Person*> tmpL;

    for (leftIndex = 0; leftIndex < leftSize; leftIndex++) { // copying our values from our master array into our subarrays
        tmpL.push_back(arr[leftIndex]);
    }
    for(rightIndex = 0; rightIndex < rightSize; rightIndex++) {
        tmpR.push_back(arr[rightIndex]);
    }

    //print(tmpL, leftSize); // print those sub arrays out for debugging
    //print(tmpR, rightSize);

    leftIndex = 0;
    rightIndex = 0;

    while (leftIndex < leftSize && rightIndex < rightSize) { // compares L and R subarrays and picks the last name first in the alphabet to go first
        if (tmpL[leftIndex]->lastName < tmpR[rightIndex]->lastName) {
            arr[masterIndex] = tmpL[leftIndex];
            leftIndex++;
        } else {
            arr[masterIndex] = tmpR[rightIndex];
            rightIndex++;
        }
        masterIndex += 1;
    }

    while (leftIndex < leftSize) { // the two following while conditions empty the remaining ordered last names from the subArray that is not empty
        arr[masterIndex] = tmpL[leftIndex];
        leftIndex++;
        masterIndex++;
    }
    while (rightIndex < rightSize) {
        arr[masterIndex] = tmpR[rightIndex];
        rightIndex++;
        masterIndex++;
    }

}

void split(vector<Person*> arr, int start, int end) {
    if (start < end) {
        int mid = (start+end) / 2;
        split(arr, start, mid);
        split(arr, mid + 1, end);
        merge(arr, start, mid, end);
    }
}

void readIn() {
    string DOB;
    string ssNumber;
    string bankBalance;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string state;
    int size;
    vector<Person*> pVector;

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("data1.txt");
    if (fin.fail()) {
        cout << ("error reading file");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (!fin.eof()) { // pulls in our data and stores it in a poiinter to a person object
        fin >> DOB >> ssNumber >> firstName >> lastName >> state >> bankBalance;
        Person *tmp = new Person(DOB, firstName, lastName, state, bankBalance);
        pVector.push_back(tmp);
    }
    size = (int) pVector.size() - 1;

    fin.close(); // closes the input stream previously opened.
    cout << size << endl;
    sleep(2);

    split(pVector, 0, size-1);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << pVector[i]->lastName << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    readIn();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `while (!fin.eof())` [is the wrong thing to do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: You are using one cast in your program. Remember the first rule of casting: Don't cast. In your case, you only need to do it because you chose a wrong type. Regarding `using namespace std;`, there's no excuse for using that. Also, avoid raw pointers, take a look at `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Once you get it working try http://codereview.stackexchange.com for a review.

Comment: `print` does not print the last array element.

Comment: Please reduce to a MVCE, most of your code here is not relevant to your problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @molbdnilo I will read that article thank you for the information and comment.

Comment: @Deduplicator I will look up why type casting is an issue. I also have not heard using namespace std is bad practice. My teachers must of presented that incorrectly to me and I will correct my knowledge on that issue. I will do the same with raw pointers. If you have any specific resources you think would be best for me to read, let me know. Otherwise, thank-you for your help!

Comment: @LokiAstari Thank you for both of your comments. I read about code reviewing and re-factoring but I didn't know there was a place on stackoverflow to do so. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @kebs I am a new user to stackoverflow and still learning how to program. I apologize for not knowing about MVCE and should have read the directions before posting. I will revise my code from all these suggestions and post my questions as a MVCE moving forward. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, you're passing the `vector` by value, i.e. it gets copied and on the call site you remain with the original one.

Try to pass the vector by reference.

```
void split(vector<Person*>&    arr, int start, int end) {
                         ^^^

void merge(vector<Person*>& arr, int start, int mid, int end) {
                         ^^^

void print(vector<Person*> const& arr, int size) {
                          ^^^^^^^  // You don't want to modify it here
```

Comment: Hey @LokiAstari, I appreciate your response! Arrays are passed by reference in C++, right? Wouldn't the vector obey the same rule? I say this as I tried it and when I ran the program the first element became every element in the array.

Comment: EDIT: I am mistaken, although an array is passed by reference, it is not correct to assume a Vector would and it is incorrect. Thank you for your comment:  I will update my code accordingly and run tests.

Comment: @BitShift: Arrays decay to pointers (not quite the same) which is a hangover from C. You can pass arrays by reference but the syntax is obtuse.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem in the code segment where u r pushing values in tmpL and tmpR vectors here in the loop u r initializing leftIndex and rightIndex both with 0 , whereas u should initialize leftIndex with start and rightIndex with mid+1 and run the loop till mid and end respectively.